# XeLaTeX doesn't find lmroman font, despite installing lmodern fonts

Tags: fonts, xetex, ubuntu, lmodern

Hi I'm a newbie to the latex world and I have tried as hard as I could, to find the answer in the forum, yet I haven't been successful.

I have installed texlive on ubuntu 18.04 via the command bellow.

```
apt-get install texlive-full
```

but while running template latex codes with xelate (in TexStudio) I get this error:

> Font TU/lmr/m/n/10=[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text at 10.0pt not
>   loadab le: Metric (TFM) file not found \normalsize

and yes I have installed lroman fonts via both

```
apt-get install fonts-lmodern
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install lmodern
```

your help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Normally, they're part of the basic distribution, and are the default with `xelatex`. How comes you had to install the full tex live?

Comment: @Bernard, actually I also want to use persian language which is easier to use with xelatex, so I was recommended to install the full version.

Comment: You can use lm-math (in opentype format) withe `unicode-math`.

Comment: @Bernard, problem is that this same method has been used on different laptops, and is working; and it would be easier for me to follow.

Comment: Either you’re doing something weird, or your distribution didn’t install properly. `TU` is LaTeX for Unicode, and `fontspec` should know to look for a TrueType or OpenType font, not a legacy font.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps: I had a similar problem with the Termux distribution on my phone. It was resolved by manually running `mktexlsr` which in your case would be `sudo mktexlsr`.

This should be done by the package post-installation routine, but maybe it is not.