# Font shape undefined in CI

Tags: xetex, fontspec, ubuntu, macos

I have a huge problem with a custom `.ttf`-font I can't get my head around for hours now.

My workflow is to write latex code locally, check it into CI which then compiles it and deploys the pdf to a website. I use a `Trebuchet MS` which is in the working directory and also checked into git.

On my machine, everything is working fine, it looks as expected. On the CI though, I get following warning:

```
[...]
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/Trebuchet_MS.ttf(1)/bx/n' undefined
66 (Font)              using `TU/Trebuchet_MS.ttf(1)/m/n' instead on input line 47
[...]
```

Of course with the expected result: different looking section and subsection headings.

My working directory looks like this:

```
├── file.tex
└── fonts/
    ├── Trebuchet_MS_Bold_Italic.ttf
    ├── Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf
    ├── Trebuchet_MS_Italic.ttf
    └── Trebuchet_MS.ttf
```

My tex code looks like this:

```
%&program=xelatex

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setmainfont[
    Path = fonts/,
    BoldFont = Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf,
    ItalicFont = Trebuchet_MS_Italic.ttf,
    BoldItalicFont = Trebuchet_MS_Bold_Italic.ttf
]{Trebuchet_MS.ttf}

\newfontfamily\sectionfont[
    Path = fonts/,
    BoldFont = Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf,
    ItalicFont = Trebuchet_MS_Italic.ttf,
    BoldItalicFont = Trebuchet_MS_Bold_Italic.ttf
]{Trebuchet_MS.ttf}

\setkomafont{section}{\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\sectionfont\selectfont}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\fontsize{12pt}{12pt}\selectfont\sectionfont}

\chead{\includegraphics[width=1.65cm]{img/logo.png}}

\setlength\headheight{75pt}

\renewcommand\thesection{§\arabic{section}}

\sloppy

\begin{document}

\begin{center}

{\textbf{\huge{Large Heading}}}\newline

issue \today

\end{center}

\begin{section}{Section Heading}       % <---

Some text.

\begin{subsection}{Subsection Heading} % <---

Some more text.

\end{subsection}
\end{section}

\end{document}
```

I did check the versions on both machines:

- My machine is macOS `XeTex Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (TeX Live 2020)`
- CI is Ubuntu `XeTex Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)`

So for me that looks like such a small difference that it is more than unlikely this is the cause. Also I believe I was on a much older version on my Mac when it worked already but I'm not sure.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: When running `xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -vv" file` I get following output:

```
[...]

[[2] [3] [4<FONTMAP:/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map><FONTMAP:/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap/kanjix.map><FONTMAP:/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/ckx.map>No dvi filename specified, reading standard input.

[...]

[5><AGL:pdfglyphlist.txt><AGL:glyphlist.txt>[1(Image:img/logo.png[./img/logo.png][PNG])<./fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf@20.66pt
xdvipdfmx:warning: File name="./fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf" format="opentype fonts" might be found in different location than I expected:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   ./fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Please adjust your TEXMF as conformant with:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   http://www.tug.org/ftp/tex/tds-1.1/tds.html#Fonts
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> I searched it with fooling kpathsea as progname="dvipdfmx" format="other binary files".
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Default search path for this format file is:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   /nonesuch
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Please read "README" file.
<NATIVE-FONTMAP:./fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf/0/H/65536/0/0>
fontmap: ./fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf/0/H/65536/0/0 -> ./fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf(Identity-H)

pdf_font>> Input encoding "Identity-H" requires at least 2 bytes.
pdf_font>> The -m <00> option will be assumed for "./fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf".

xdvipdfmx:warning: File name="./fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf" format="opentype fonts" might be found in different location than I expected:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   ./fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Please adjust your TEXMF as conformant with:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   http://www.tug.org/ftp/tex/tds-1.1/tds.html#Fonts
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> I searched it with fooling kpathsea as progname="dvipdfmx" format="other binary files".
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Default search path for this format file is:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   /nonesuch
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Please read "README" file.
(CID:TrebuchetMS-Bold)
pdf_font>> Type0 font "./fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf" cmap_id=<Identity-H,0> opened at font_id=<./fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf/0/H/65536/0/0,0>.><./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf@10.91pt

xdvipdfmx:warning: File name="./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf" format="opentype fonts" might be found in different location than I expected:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   ./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Please adjust your TEXMF as conformant with:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   http://www.tug.org/ftp/tex/tds-1.1/tds.html#Fonts
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> I searched it with fooling kpathsea as progname="dvipdfmx" format="other binary files".
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Default search path for this format file is:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   /nonesuch
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Please read "README" file.
<NATIVE-FONTMAP:./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf/0/H/65536/0/0>
fontmap: ./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf/0/H/65536/0/0 -> ./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf(Identity-H)

pdf_font>> Input encoding "Identity-H" requires at least 2 bytes.
pdf_font>> The -m <00> option will be assumed for "./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf".

xdvipdfmx:warning: File name="./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf" format="opentype fonts" might be found in different location than I expected:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   ./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Please adjust your TEXMF as conformant with:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   http://www.tug.org/ftp/tex/tds-1.1/tds.html#Fonts
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> I searched it with fooling kpathsea as progname="dvipdfmx" format="other binary files".
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Default search path for this format file is:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   /nonesuch
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Please read "README" file.
(CID:TrebuchetMS)
pdf_font>> Type0 font "./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf" cmap_id=<Identity-H,0> opened at font_id=<./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf/0/H/65536/0/0,1>.><./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf@13.95pt

xdvipdfmx:warning: File name="./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf" format="opentype fonts" might be found in different location than I expected:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   ./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Please adjust your TEXMF as conformant with:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   http://www.tug.org/ftp/tex/tds-1.1/tds.html#Fonts
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> I searched it with fooling kpathsea as progname="dvipdfmx" format="other binary files".
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Default search path for this format file is:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   /nonesuch
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Please read "README" file.

fontmap: ./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf/0/H/65536/0/0 -> ./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf(Identity-H)[map:<00>]

xdvipdfmx:warning: File name="./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf" format="opentype fonts" might be found in different location than I expected:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   ./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Please adjust your TEXMF as conformant with:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   http://www.tug.org/ftp/tex/tds-1.1/tds.html#Fonts
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> I searched it with fooling kpathsea as progname="dvipdfmx" format="other binary files".
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Default search path for this format file is:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   /nonesuch
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Please read "README" file.
(CID:TrebuchetMS)
pdf_font>> Type0 font "./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf" cmap_id=<Identity-H,0> opened at font_id=<./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf/0/H/65536/0/0,2>.>][2]<./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf@11.96pt

xdvipdfmx:warning: File name="./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf" format="opentype fonts" might be found in different location than I expected:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   ./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Please adjust your TEXMF as conformant with:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   http://www.tug.org/ftp/tex/tds-1.1/tds.html#Fonts
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> I searched it with fooling kpathsea as progname="dvipdfmx" format="other binary files".
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Default search path for this format file is:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   /nonesuch
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Please read "README" file.

fontmap: ./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf/0/H/65536/0/0 -> ./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf(Identity-H)[map:<00>]

xdvipdfmx:warning: File name="./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf" format="opentype fonts" might be found in different location than I expected:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   ./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Please adjust your TEXMF as conformant with:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   http://www.tug.org/ftp/tex/tds-1.1/tds.html#Fonts
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> I searched it with fooling kpathsea as progname="dvipdfmx" format="other binary files".
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Default search path for this format file is:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   /nonesuch
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Please read "README" file.
(CID:TrebuchetMS)
pdf_font>> Type0 font "./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf" cmap_id=<Identity-H,0> opened at font_id=<./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf/0/H/65536/0/0,3>.>][3][4][5 [6]][6

[7<./fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf@10.91pt]
xdvipdfmx:warning: File name="./fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf" format="opentype fonts" might be found in different location than I expected:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   ./fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Please adjust your TEXMF as conformant with:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   http://www.tug.org/ftp/tex/tds-1.1/tds.html#Fonts
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> I searched it with fooling kpathsea as progname="dvipdfmx" format="other binary files".
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Default search path for this format file is:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   /nonesuch
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Please read "README" file.

fontmap: ./fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf/0/H/65536/0/0 -> ./fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf(Identity-H)[map:<00>]

xdvipdfmx:warning: File name="./fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf" format="opentype fonts" might be found in different location than I expected:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   ./fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Please adjust your TEXMF as conformant with:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   http://www.tug.org/ftp/tex/tds-1.1/tds.html#Fonts
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> I searched it with fooling kpathsea as progname="dvipdfmx" format="other binary files".
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Default search path for this format file is:
xdvipdfmx:warning: >>   /nonesuch
xdvipdfmx:warning: >> Please read "README" file.
(CID:TrebuchetMS-Bold)
pdf_font>> Type0 font "./fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf" cmap_id=<Identity-H,0> opened at font_id=<./fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf/0/H/65536/0/0,4>.>][7 [8] (./agb.aux)][8]

otf_cmap>> Creating ToUnicode CMap for "./fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf"...
otf_cmap>> Creating ToUnicode CMap for "./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf"...
(CID:./fonts/Trebuchet_MS_Bold.ttf[SBUEJS+TrebuchetMS-Bold][CIDFontType2][21 glyphs (Max CID: 108)][12245 bytes])(CID:./fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf[QIPVEC+TrebuchetMS][CIDFontType2][77 glyphs (Max CID: 197)][31017 bytes])(CID)(CID)(CID)

[...]
```

Also I tried to "adjust my TEXMF as conformant with http://www.tug.org/ftp/tex/tds-1.1/tds.html#Fonts" but that URL only gets me a 404.

I also noticed, that something like `{\textbf{\huge{Testline}}}` works as expected - the font is right and it's bold as well. Which is even more confusing because obviously the font is loaded and works. Just not for `\section` and `\subsection`.

EDIT: So I tried installing the font on the CI machine using Ubuntu package `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`. According to the `apt-get`-logs everything is okay and I can locate the font in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts`. I also run `mktexlsr` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/484840/xelatex-doesnt-find-lmroman-font-despite-installing-lmodern-fonts).

I changed the font selection to

```
\setmainfont{Trebuchet MS}
\newfontfamily\sectionfont{Trebuchet MS}
```

I still get similar logs from XeLaTex but this time I get

```
pdf_font>> Input encoding "Identity-H" requires at least 2 bytes.
538 pdf_font>> The -m <00> option will be assumed for "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/trebuc.ttf".
539 (CID:TrebuchetMS)
```

additionally. But at least the TEXMF conformation notice is gone.

Comment: I see no reason for this. I tried also with TL 2018 and 2019, just to be sure. Can you try running `xelatex -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -vv" file` on the CI machine and report the output you get on the console? Just the final part with the information on fonts.

Comment: @egreg I edited the question accordingly